# Where can I get information on the mechanics of fonts?

Tags: fonts

Following my line of "simple" questions: where can I find information about how fonts are made/rendered, and details like what hinting is?

**Edit:** I'd like more details about font rendering.

Comment: I realize this question is two years old, but... why are you asking where to get information instead of just asking for the information you want?

Comment: @Lord: I.... don't know :S

Answer (score 16, accepted):

There is an open source font creation app [fontforge](http://fontforge.sourceforge.net/), that has a very helpful help page describing many of the fundamentals of font construction:

http://fontforge.sourceforge.net/overview.html#TOC

and hinting specifically is here:

[image: hinting]

http://fontforge.sourceforge.net/hinting.html

**Some more font building & hinting resources:** [iLT how to make a font part II](http://ilovetypography.com/2007/10/29/so-you-want-to-create-a-font-part-2/) — ❧ —[Truetype Hinting](http://www.truetype-typography.com/tthints.htm) — ❧ — [Adobe opntype font development kit](http://www.adobe.com/devnet/opentype/afdko/topic_overview.html) ⊃ [Adobe opentype hinting information](http://www.adobe.com/devnet/opentype/archives/hinting.html) — ❧ —[Hinting tutorial from the DejaVu designers](http://dejavu-fonts.org/wiki/index.php?title=Hinting_tutorial/The_stack)

**Rendering Articles:** [How does sub-pixel rendering work?](http://www.grc.com/ct/ctwhat.htm) — ❧ — [Font smoothing, anti-aliasing, and sub-pixel rendering](http://www.joelonsoftware.com/items/2007/06/12.html)

And just for fun:

[image]

[{source}](https://www.chank.com/howto/makeafont/)

Comment: lol, that's pretty good....

Comment: I actually already saw the joel on software blog link, but not the GRC one, thanks!

Comment: I'd upvote you a couple more times if i could. This looks like the best answer, i think you deserve the bounty! however don't let that stop you from looking, it's great to see so many articles on fonts.

Comment: Thanks RCIX - will keep adding resources as I find them ;-)

Answer (score 5):

[I Love Typography](http://ilovetypography.com/) has some great info on fonts and font creation.

Answer (score 4):

After designing a font with the tool of your choice (the Adobe Suite is fine for this), throw it into [FontLab](http://www.fontlab.com/) and make the necessary changes then export it.

[This](http://www.vectoralia.com/typephases/fontcreation1.html) guide covers the process fairly in-depth.

Answer (score 3):

If you are interested in the technology behind font rendering you should see if this article is what you are looking for. It is very good.

[Texts Rasterization Exposures](http://www.antigrain.com/research/font_rasterization/index.html)

Answer (score 2):

[Typophile](http://typophile.com/) is a great website devoted to type. They have excellent forums frequented by people who actually design type so I think you will have more luck there.

Comment: Seems interesting but i was never to fond of websites almost completely in flash, and i'm also not too big on forums. Thanks anyway!

Answer (score 2):

There is also an app called **[The Typography Manual](http://typographyapp.com/)** for the iPhone and iPod Touch.

Comment: Looks neat! i'll definitely keep an eye on that.